# SQL Update using a joined where clause

Tags: t-sql, join, sql-update, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to write an update query using a Where clause join to a different table but can't get it to work and can't see anything about this specific issue. The query I have got so far is:

```
UPDATE Supplieritem
INNER JOIN  item 
  ON supplieritem.itemid = item.itemid
SET SupplierItemCode = 'COL2708WTEST';
WHERE  item.Code = 'AAH30000000'
```

I'm sure this must be possible and that I am missing something simple.

Comment: what is your dbms

Comment: Please provide the error message that you get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax works in MS SQL Server

```
UPDATE t
SET SupplierItemCode = 'COL2708WTEST'
FROM Supplieritem t
JOIN item i ON t.itemid = i.itemid
WHERE i.Code = 'AAH30000000';
```

This syntax works in Postgresql:

```
UPDATE Supplieritem t
SET SupplierItemCode = 'COL2708WTEST'
FROM item i 
WHERE t.itemid = i.itemid
  AND i.Code = 'AAH30000000';
```